# Web Essentials add-in is not shown on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I have installed all packages of Web Essentials 2017, but the add-in that usually is shown on browser is not visible, although I'm pressing `Ctrl`. It's a problem because I use inspect option a lot.

It is working on Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Web Essentials 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017) is no just a collection of specific extensions. Which specific extension do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what extension is. I guess that Browser Sync. In the previous version, you can see an overlay with all the options in browser. One of them was intercept.